# Retrieve URL from iframe using window.postMessage

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

I'm trying to access the URL of an iFrame that I open on my site.  The iFrame is from another domain so traditional methods violate the same origin policy and are flagged as cross site scripting.  However, I just discovered window.postMessage, but I don't quite know how to pull it all together.

My goal is to capture the final URL in the iFrame.  For example, a user clicks a button on my site to open an iFrame.  Say that iFrame loads a web site and the user clicks around on the site.  When they close the iFrame, I want to capture the URL so the next time they click the button on my site, I can open the iFrame to the same state that the site was in last time they visited.  Is this possible with window.postMessage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.iframe[name].src 
document.iframe[name].document.location.href
```

Comment: Both of those don't work.  I get Javascript errors:  Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://mysite..com/ from frame with URL http://anothersite.com/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: @scottystang Did they work in the end? If they still dont work then why is this the correct answer

Comment: You need to understand cross domain script security issue before you implement it. You cannot run ur script on page from different domain.